# How to add people to a task to reduce time in MS project

Tags: ms-project, product-management, resources

How do I add people to a task to reduce the duration of a task? I have a automatically scheduled task that takes 15 days to complete with one person assigned when i try to add people it doesn't reduce the time it takes to complete the task. I am not good with MS Project and need to do this to complete an assessment for college but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select "fixed work" instead of "fixed duration."  You can find that functionality in the Task Information area.  When you have fixed work selected, and you add a resource, that will change the duration.  If you have fixed duration selected and you add resources, it will reduce resource utilization percentage.

Comment: It won't let me change the task type, it's highlighted gray

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure the issue.  You are opening the leaf / lowest task to change its type?  There are some really good project experts on this exchange so hopefully they will jump in with a better answer.

Comment: Ah I wasn't selecting opening that I have sorted it now thank you very much for your help it is really appreciated :)

Comment: @user45237 Glad this answered your question--don't forget to mark the  answer as accepted.